# Vue: axios не работает, не могу понять почему

Tags: vue.js, axios

У меня есть такой код

```
this.$http.get('/doctor/getover')
        .then(result => {
          console.log('[Result]', result)
          this.doctors = result.data.doctors
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log('[Error]', error)
        })
```

Когда я отправляю этот запрос - я получаю сообщение о том, что пустой ответ
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если я просто подставлю эту ссылку в браузер - все работает хорошо, данные отдаются.
Подскажите что не так

Comment: Возможно проблема в Coors'ах

Comment: Ест ли ошибки в консоле?

Comment: нет и нет. корсы настроены. такое ощущение, что какой то кеш, не могу только понять где: на сервере или фронте